# Linkedin Ads Reporting returning empty 'elements' array for a given campaign

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get some information about a specific LinkedIn campaign, but I'm getting an empty 'elements' array as response.

The catch is that the campaign has zero in all metrics when looking on the Campaign Manager. I think it was never actually veiculated, because even the cost is zero (and the status is COMPLETED).

My doubt is: should the array actually be empty, or be filled with zero on the values of the metrics and I'm messing up the requests?

---

This is what I'm doing:

First a GET request to see all campaigns that are associated with that Token:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search
```

and this a part of the response:

```
...
"costType": "CPC",
"name": "Posts", 
"offsiteDeliveryEnabled": true
"id": 128237464,
...
```

Then another GET request to see the info about that campaign:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=25&dateRange.start.month=6&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:128237464
```

But this is the response:

```
{
    "elements": [],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

My app has the `r_ads_reporting` permission and `Development tier` on the Marketing Developer Platform.

I've also manually added the account ID of that company on the MDP Settings.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the `adAnalyticsV2` endpoint (which you mentioned). Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the campaigns I used. After this I tested with some campaigns that had real ads and I got the expected response

Comment: I received the following response from LinkedIn (via linkedin.com/help/linkedin as there is no way to contact the developers directly):

`If no count param is provided, it'll default to count=10 even if there is no ad data to return. If you set the count param to 5,000 in the request, you will see the count field equal to 5,000 in the response. The lack of data in the response means the requested ads object (e.g. a campaign) doesn't have any data to return.`

So it seems the `count` parameter is just echoing the param it is supplied, and doesn't actually indicate that there is any data.

Comment: That was my source of confusion anyway. I assumed that the count value indicated how many elements there were supposed to be in the response.